# getting types_hash_max_size error in /var/llog/nginx/error.log when restarting nginx

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

I ma getting the below error in /var/log/nginx/error.log file:

2017/02/07 16:18:53 [warn] 775#0: could not build optimal types_hash, you should
 increase either types_hash_max_size: 2048 or types_hash_bucket_size: 64; ignori
ng types_hash_bucket_size

I have already checked nginx.conf it has the following value

types_hash_max_size 2048;

How can I know the current value of types_hash_max_size and types_hash_bucket_size from the linux and how to resolve the above issue.

Any help will be highly appreciated!

thanks,
BR.

Answer (score 1):

The warning message shows the *current* value, *not* the suggested value.

In case you get this warning, you should set the value to *double* its existing value, which should be a power of 2. And as explained in the documentation, if you are warned about two values, you should [increase hash max size first](https://nginx.org/en/docs/hash.html).

```
types_hash_max_size 4096;
```

Comment: thanks a lot Michael, is there any way to increase the value of the types_hash_max_size without restarting the nginx like setting it from Linux   command line

Comment: Reload, not restart.